# How safe is it to write html pages on a live server in PHP

Tags: php, html, linux, server, live

Just a quick Q: How safe is it to write html pages in PHP? From what I understand this isn't ACID compliant so user may experience errors if they see a page mid write??

The thing is I have seen several websites use this technique. Should I write the page then use sys links (which is apparently ACID safe, but requires a system() call).

Comment: Unless you're getting billions of pageviews a month I wouldn't worry about it. The chances of someone hitting that page in the microsecond or two the write takes is tiny, and they'd likely just refresh.

Comment: This is crazy and worrying about it is pointless. You're about a million times more likely to introduce a typo and show an error to *everybody* than to have somebody request the page while it's been written to disk. There are lots of reasons to not edit live code in production, this isn't one of them.

Comment: If you are using some framework, than you will be writing PHP separated from HTML and only some variables will be printed out in HTML. Also, there is no big latency for printing out HTML via PHP (unless it's few thousands lines of HTML, but still, will see it only when PHP done it's job).

Comment: I like this optimistic Stackoverflow..What happened?